# How to find all TFS changesets affecting any file within a directory?

Tags: version-control, tfs

Over the last few months, I've been doing some maintenance on a project with many source files.  I was recently informed that there is an issue with one of my bug-fixes and I was asked to fix my bug-fix.

However, since there are so many files and folders within the project, I can't remember which one I modified.

Therefore, I would like to be able to search within the root directory of the project for changesets that have affected files within the folder.  I'm sure that I could determine which changeset caused the problem by the comments I put on them.

---

How can I find all TFS changesets that affect at least one file within a specific folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in viewing the history for a single folder, navigate to that folder in Source Control Explorer, right-click on it and select "View History".

This will show you all the changesets that have affected this folder.

Comment: Simple answer!  I think that I already tried this, but it didn't find what I was looking for, so I thought I must be doing something wrong.  I must have checked in two bug-fixes together and only commented one or somesuch.

Comment: If you track Bugs as TFS Work Items and link Changesets to WI's, this would be much easier for you.  You could simply lookup the Bug workitem and view linked changesets.

Comment: I just want to comment that it would be more ideally integrated in Visual Studio if one could right click on a solution or project in the solution explorer and select a command that would find all changesets containing files in that solution/project.  It's a bit cumbersome switching to SCE for this.  I wonder if the VS team has considered this.